Dauernd vs. häufig
Was ist bitte der Unterschied zwischen "dauernd" und "häufig"? Die beiden haben im Wörterbuch ähnliche Bedeutungen. Wann verwenden wir welches Wort im richtigen Kontext?

In welchem Wörterbuch hast Du nachgeschaut? Und was hast Du dort gefunden? Bei DWDS (deutsch-deutsch) oder Leo (deutsch-englisch) sind die Erläuterungen bzw. Übersetzungen sehr unterschiedlich, ohne jegliche Überlappung.

@Raketenolli: ist der Name des Wörterbuchs nicht völlig unerheblich? Zum Beispiel lassen die Lemmata "dauernd" und "häufig" im Campe (Joachim Heinrich Campe, Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb10523276?page=575) eine gewisse Übereinstimmung erkennen.

Natürlich ist das relevant, z. B. ob es sich bei "Wörterbuch" um ein deutsch-deutsches Wörterbuch wie DWDS, Duden, oder ein fremdsprachlich-deutsches Wörterbuch handelt, oder evtl. auch nur um Google Translate oder oder. Damit wir hier nachvollziehen können, was denn genau "ähnliche Bedeutungen" sind und Missverständnisse ausräumen oder Unklarheiten aufklären können. Zumal Übersetzungen in andere Sprachen immer verlustbehaftet sind, und der Umfang dieses Verlustes deutlich von der Zielsprache abhängen kann.

"Häufig" ist eine Weiterbildung von "Haufen", also eine (ungeordnete, aber größere) Ansammlung von Dingen. Es bezeichnet die Frequenz, mit der ein bestimmtes Ereignis eintritt, nämlich "oftmalig". Mögliche Gegenteile wäre etwa "selten" oder "manchmal", als Synonyme kommen "oft", "öfters" oder "vielmals" in Frage.
Zu beachten ist, daß diese ungefähren Angaben allesamt eben ungefähr sind, es also keinen verbindlichen Maßstab gibt, was unter "häufig" zu verstehen ist und um wieviele Male es öfter als "regelmäßig" oder weniger oft als "fast immer" passiert.

Ich gehe häufig ins Kino.

Kann etwa für einen Sprecher "einmal pro Woche" bedeuten, während derselbe mit

Ich trinke häufig Kaffee.

vielleicht meint, daß er täglich 5 Tassen zu sich nimmt.
"Dauernd" ist ein ähnlicher Fall, ist aber von "Dauer" abgeleitet. Es wird ähnlich eingesetzt wie "häufig", bezeichnet aber tendenziell nicht einzelne, zählbare Ereignisse sondern Zeitspannen, auch wenn es in der Verwendung durchaus Überschneidungen gibt.
Man kann zwar häufig einen Kaffee trinken (weil hier auf die Einzelaktivität "einen Kaffee trinken" abgestellt wird, die zählbar ist) und man kann dauernd Kaffee trinken (weil hier das Kaffeetrinken schlechthin angesprochen wird, mit dem man sich eine bestimmte Zeitspanne beschäftigt), aber man kann nicht dauernd einen Kaffee trinken. Es ist auch ein Unterschied, ob man häufig krank ist (da hat man in hoher Frequenz verschiedene Krankheiten) oder ob man dauernd krank ist (da hat man vielleicht nur eine Krankheit, die aber sehr langwierig ist).
Allerdings gibt es im süddeutschen Raum die - ironisierende - Wendung "dauernd etwas tun", wobei hier "dauernd" als Synonym für "ständig" verwendet wird. In der Hochsprache würde ich allerdings von diesem Gebrauch absehen.

DWDS finde ich hier nicht sehr hilfreich, eher so den Duden. Der macht klar, dass dauernd zwei Bedeutungen hat:

Einerseits "für längere Zeit in gleichbleibender Weise vorhanden" wie in "dauernder Wohnsitz" und "die Gefahr war dauernd vorhanden".
Andererseits aber auch als "häufig auftretend" wie in "dauernde Störungen".

Dass diese Bedeutungen sehr unterschiedlich sind, sieht man daran, dass es in obigen Bespielen zwar eine Zeit ohne Störungen gibt, aber keine ohne Gefahr.
In der zweiten Bedeutung ist es (für mich) ein Synonym für andauernd (laut Duden [in ärgerlicher oder lästiger Weise] unausgesetzt, fortwährend; immer wieder).
Der Unterschied zwischen häufig und dauernd hat nun damit zu tun, wie dir auffällt, dass etwas häufig ist. Du sagst nur dauernd, wenn es in irgendeiner Art auffällig ist. Es ist, als würdest du sagen: "Wenn du ihn siehst, gibt es eine große Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass er gerade das tut." Die ersten zwei Bespiele bei DWDS in dieser Bedeutung lauten:

Ich finde es auch eines Oberbürgermeisters unwürdig, dauernd mit Provokationen zu polarisieren.


[Faber war] durch seinen Beruf dauernd unterwegs.

"Häufig" ist viel neutraler. Sagst du:

Er trinkt dauernd Kaffee,

so ist es dir aufgefallen und du findest das möglicherweise nicht gut. Sagst du nur

Er trinkt häufig Kaffee,

ist das eine neutrale Aussage.
